# Use "this" in static method in android

Tags: java, android

This is my first android app so maybe this is a stupid question. So, please consider if I am doing any mistake.

I am building a app related to bluetooth.

I have a method in my `MainActivity.java`:

```
public void showDeviceListDialog() {
    BluetoothDeviceListDialog dialog = new BluetoothDeviceListDialog(this);
    dialog.setOnDeviceSelectedListener(this);
    dialog.setTitle("Paired Devices");
    dialog.setDevices(bluetoothSerial.getPairedDevices());
    dialog.showAddress(true);
    dialog.show();
}
```

I need to call this method from another fragment. So, when I call this method like this: `MainActivity.showDeviceListDialog();` it is asking for making the method *Static*. But when I am making it *Static* I am getting errors on "***this***" **[** `dialog.setOnDeviceSelectedListener(`***this***`);` **]** on my method.

I have already read some posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16315488/this-cannot-use-this-in-static-context) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21338785/using-this-in-parameters-of-static-methods-in-static-class) but I didn't got help about my problem.

I have tried this from my fragment:

```
 MainActivity mc = new MainActivity();
 mc.showDeviceListDialog();
```

but this is showing NullPointerException.

So, Please tell me how to call it from my fragment without this errors.
Thank you.

Comment: You can use interface as a callback to the activity. Never do `MainActivity mc = new MainActivity();`

Comment: You can't instantiate your activity

Comment: you can't use `this` with `static`. You shouldn't use `new` on classes that extend `Activity` as well

Comment: @Raghunandan please give some more details about this

Comment: @Blackbelt obviously you can do it, but that doesn't mean that you should

Comment: I suggest stepping back from your current activity and working through some basic Java tutorials.

Comment: Using Fragment , Call `getActivity ()`

Comment: guys, this is NOT a DUPLICATE. although the question seem about the usage of `static` method, the solution he is asking does not really involve creating a static method. this is a matter of **accessing an activity from Fragment**.

Comment: @Blackbelt I was asking for a solution to call a non-static method of a activity from a fragment. Not asking what is a static method and why I cant use 'this' in static method. So, my question is not a duplicate of this questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `Fragment` has a [`getActivity()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getActivity()) method which returns the `Activity` associated with the `Fragment`.

Therefore, you can call this method from a `Fragment` without making it `static` :

```
getActivity ().showDeviceListDialog ();
```

EDIT (thanks to user1506104's comment) :

Actually, you'll have to cast the `Activity` returned by `getActivity()` to `MainActivity` in order to call that method :

```
((MainActivity) getActivity ()).showDeviceListDialog ();
```

This is assuming the `Fragment` is associated with an `Activity` of that type.

Comment: this should work given that the fragment in question is a child of the Activity that has `showDeviceListDialog()`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Eran. It just worked! XD

Answer (score 1):

**this** is a reference pointing to the current instance, therefore makes no sence in static methods
...
and doing something like

```
MainActivity mc = new MainActivity();
```

is not the way android wants you to create an activity...
you need to get the Activity like calling the `getActivity()`; method

Comment: thanks for the comment

Comment: Doesn't really address the solution of the initial problem, which was calling the activity method. OP simply allowed the IDE to make the method static

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create activity like that : MainActivity mc = new MainActivity(); . Android is responsible for this. Use Intent instead. 
See this tutorial https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html about static methods.

Comment: we should not be inlcuding URLs in answers section